# Getting the string from the server side and separating the code fragment from the string in Kotlin

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, frontend

I made an Android application where the users ask questions, but they may use programming codes in their questions. How can I separate the programming codes from the normal texts in Kotlin? If you can explain, I want to change the background of the codes. Like this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/azZe4.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use something just like stackoverflow i.e. put code between "```" and you can easily parse it from string.

More info: to parse string you can use [Regex](https://www.w3schools.com/java/java_regex.asp)

here's some sample code that detects "```" and changes inner text to red:

````
...
onCreate(){
textView.setText(formatString("alo ```alo```"));
}
...
SpannableStringBuilder formatString(String message) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(```)(.*?)(```)");// detects the pattern ```*``` in the string
        Matcher matcher = p.matcher(message);

        SpannableStringBuilder spannable = new SpannableStringBuilder(message);
        //for changing color of text
        while (matcher.find()) {
            ForegroundColorSpan span = new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED);
            spannable.setSpan(span, matcher.start(), matcher.end(), Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

            spannable.replace(spannable.getSpanStart(span), spannable.getSpanStart(span) + 3, "");
            spannable.replace(spannable.getSpanEnd(span) - 3, spannable.getSpanEnd(span), ""); //to remove ``` from string

        }
        return spannable;
    }
````

Comment: I know that regular expressions can be used, but I don't know the algorithm, at least I can do it myself if someone guides me.

Comment: @Mikaiil I edited my answer and added sample code